# Get physical position of device with Python?

Tags: python, geolocation

Is there a way to get the computer's physical position using Python, preferably without an API, or with a free API? I've searched around a bit, and the only free API I've found is very, very inaccurate. I only need this to be somewhat accurate, as it's for getting local weather.

Comment: 1. what have you tried, 2. how precise are you looking for?

Comment: @mfrankli I've searched for "IP geolocation API", and IP2location.com is the only thing I found. I live in a major city, and the example on their site for my IP is way off. It is for finding local weather, so ≈50 miles is OK, but the one I found is almost a state off.

Comment: you might want to update your question to reflect those things (especially the latter).

Comment: IP-based location detection is not always very good at all.  You should check the tools you try when connected through other ISPs or from other locations (friend's house, etc), and also check your reported location across multiple tools from each location.  Don't be too quick to blame the tool, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scrape it from a webpage like http://www.geoiptool.com/ for example.

Comment: Scraping is not ideal, the usage of a web API is significantly better because it is less susceptible to parsing changes.  See my answer below.

Comment: @JasonParham http://freegeoip.net/ is currently not working, Scraping or using a web API are worse than using the `GeoIP` database which you can be download offline and you don't have to worry about these services being down or the time taken to download the data from server

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [MaxMind's GeoIP Python API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python) with their free [GeoLite City database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite). Accuracy may vary, more [details here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolite_city_accuracy).

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2543018/222758) for other alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

```
import urllib2
import json

# Automatically geolocate the connecting IP
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
json_string = f.read()
f.close()
location = json.loads(json_string)
print(location)
location_city = location['city']
location_state = location['region_name']
location_country = location['country_name']
location_zip = location['zipcode']
```

Send HTTP GET requests to: freegeoip.net/{format}/{ip_or_hostname} to receive a JSON output that Python can parse.

I get the following JSON keys, which should be sufficient for what you are needing:

- ip
- country_code
- country_name
- region_code
- region_name
- city
- zipcode
- latitude
- longitude
- metro_code
- area_code

Comment: "This API endpoint is deprecated and has now been shut down."

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to get the computer's physical position using Python, preferably without an API, or with a free API

Yes. With **[IPinfo.io](https://www.ipinfo.io)** you can make up 50,000 requests/month for free. If you want to get weather data you can use the provided `region` or `city` values by doing an IP Geolocation lookup. You can use the IPinfo API either by using the request library to communicate with the API or using the [IPinfo Python Library](https://github.com/ipinfo/python)

#### Method 1: Using the API with `requests`

```py
import requests

# here I have generated this IP address randomly
ip_address = "19.145.189.86"

# get your token from your IPinfo account dashboard
token = ""

# using f-string here. Use any method to create the URL
url = f"https://ipinfo.io/{ip_address}?token={token}"

# json response after the IP lookup
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

The response dictionary will look like this:

```json
{
  "ip": "19.145.189.86",
  "city": "Dearborn",
  "region": "Michigan",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "42.2399,-83.1508",
  "postal": "48121",
  "timezone": "America/Detroit"
}
```

To get the most accurate weather prediction, use the `city` or the `region` value. So from the `response` dictionary lookup the values for `city` and `region`

```py
>>> response['city']
"Dearborn"

>>> response['region']
"Dearborn"
```

#### Method 2: Using the Python library

The IPinfo Python library makes this process much easier. Install it with `pip`. [IPinfo Python Documentation](https://github.com/ipinfo/python)

```py
# install with `pip install ipinfo`
import ipinfo

# initialize handler with access token
access_token = "insert_your_token_here"
handler = ipinfo.getHandler(access_token)

ip_address = '19.145.189.86'
details = handler.getDetails(ip_address)
```

From the `details` variable you can now find the individual information you need.

```py
>>> details.city
'Dearborn'

>>> details.region
'Michigan'
```

Answer (score 0):

I rediscovered another weather API which I don't like quite as much (Weather Underground), but can optionally determine the location. Might use this if I can't something like a geoiptool scraper to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the public IP of the device then you can do so by using [freegeip](https://freegeoip.net/). Below is the Python 3.4.2 code for getting location and time zone.

```
>>> import requests
>>> ip = '141.70.111.66'
>>> url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'+ip
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> js = r.json()
>>> js['country_code']
'DE'
>>> js['country_name']
'Germany'
>>> js['time_zone']
'Europe/Berlin'
>>> js['city']
'Stuttgart'
>>> js.items()
dict_items([('latitude', 48.7667), ('ip', '141.70.111.66'), ('region_code', 'BW'), ('country_code', 'DE'), ('city', 'Stuttgart'), ('zip_code', '70173'), ('country_name', 'Germany'), ('longitude', 9.1833), ('region_name', 'Baden-Württemberg Region'), ('time_zone', 'Europe/Berlin'), ('metro_code', 0)])
```

Comment: "This API endpoint is deprecated and has now been shut down."

Answer (score 0):

get in
https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html
find, its veary easy my friend
folium.plugins.LocateControl

Comment: Seba Ledezma, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).